# How to fix "Django test setUp() function not creating the django users"?

Tags: django, python-2.7, ubuntu

I am doing the django test cases. Now I have a problem that, user created in django test is not shown in the database created for test. consider my database name as db.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User,AnonymousUser
from django.test import TestCase,LiveServerTestCase
from django.db import connection


class machinelist(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        self.user=User.objects.create_user(username="vishnu***",email="vishnu@clartrum.com",password="vishnu@12345")
        print self.user.username
        db_name = connection.settings_dict['NAME']
        print db_name

        t=raw_input("PAUSE")

    def tearDown(self):
        print 'd'

    def test1(self):#view function
        print "2"
```

The output will print the username `vishnu***` and db_name as `test_db`. But when you observe the database, there is no data.

In the code, when the `raw_input` is executed, I will sign into the mysql server and verified that `test_db` is created successfully and also the django's tables. But when i checked auth_user table there is no data in it.

I am using django 1.11.20 and mysql 5.6.33.

Why User is not updating on the database table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tests inside TestCase classes run in a transaction, which is rolled back at the end of each test. Since the default MySQL transaction isolation level is REPEATABLE READ, the data inserted within the transaction is not visible from outside.

I'm not sure why you want to check the data from outside the test, though. You can print it or assert on it from within the test itself.

Comment: In the view, i am reading the table using select sql queries and at that time it gives empty result. view function take different mysqldb connection and we are using python-mysqldb for connecting it.

Comment: Also If I create the user inside the setUpClass(), it will work. we can see the data in it ( provided no superClass is used)

Comment: Well I don't see how any of that contradicts what I said. You're using a different SQL connection. REPEATABLE READ means other connections don't see data inserted into a different transaction until it's committeed. But **why** would you do this? Why use SQL at all in the view rather than the ORM, and why use a different connection?

Comment: we are not using django models since it has some drawbacks like no provision for multiple primary keys. Our company relay on python mysql. Can you please answer Why it visible if I used it in setUpClass()???

Comment: [https://mydbops.wordpress.com/2018/06/22/back-to-basics-isolation-levels-in-mysql/]      from this link. It is given that if select command executed then the same result is used throughout the transaction. Here the select command is used only once and it is used after the create command. So it should work right?

Comment: No that's not what it says. It says what I said, that in REPEATABLE READ you don't see uncommitted changes in another transaction. And `setUpClass` works because that is done before the transaction is opened, see [the code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/test/testcases.py#L1123).

Comment: So you are saying that setUP() doesn't commit the created users throughout the tests?. If we use `User.objects.create` it will automatically committed, right? I also tried by adding `self.user.save()` and it doesn't help me.

Comment: As I said, test cases are run inside a transaction which is automatically rolled back at the end of each test. The whole point of a test is that it runs from a known state each time and that individual tests don't affect each other; so, the transaction is never committed. If you don't want this, you can use base your test class on [TransactionTestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase) instead of TestCase; that won't wrap each test in a transaction, but will be much slower.